# What are the means to consider that a specific function is phase of an oscillator?

Tags: oscillators

I hope the experts of the field forgive me for this n00b questions, but I am just trying to understand physics. Assume the following function:

$$\phi(t)=\omega t+\cos(\omega t)$$

The above function has the property that:

$$\phi(t+T)-\phi(t)=\omega T=const.$$
Where $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$.

Now the question is based on these facts, may I consider that $\phi$ actually represents the phase of an oscillator??

NOTE: I know my question is a bit silly because I am not modelling any kind of real physical phenomenon but only introducing a function, but I imagine the function I have written is simple case of an oscillator perturbed by means of a second oscillator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any function be the phase of an oscillator.  Whatever $f(t)$ is, you can speak of $\cos (f(t))$  Your particular expression would make particular sense for phase modulation of a wave.  The carrier wave is at frequency $\omega$.  Normally the phase modulation would have smaller amplitude than $1$ and probably a lower frequency than $\omega$, but we can plot $\cos(x+\cos(x))$ and get something that is nicely periodic, though distorted from a standard cosine wave.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have additional questions. By the amplitude of one, you are talking about the coefficient of $\cos(\omega) t$ in my expression of phase, right? And my second question: So any mapping (as you applied $\cos$ here) would make sense? the only important thing is something to have the same period with the main phase, right?

Comment: Yes, the amplitude of 1 is the range of the inner cosine function.  If you want it to be truly periodic, you need the modulation to have a period that is (a multiple of) the period of the main wave.  But if you think of phase modulating a data transmission the function would be $\cos (\omega t + data)$ where data is not periodic.  The resulting wave is not truly periodic, but it is close enough for many purposes to be considered periodic.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing actually shows up both in the engineering aspects of FM radio, as well as in [semiclassical representations of intermode coupling in molecular Raman scattering](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/131/24/10.1063/1.3276684).

Since $\phi$ is periodic, trigonometric functions of $\phi$ such as $\cos(\omega t+\cos(\omega t))$ admit a Fourier series expansion obtainable by the [Jacobi-Anger identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion). The sidebands are used in FM to transmit information, and in Raman scattering they represent the interaction between two oscillators.

Answer (score 0):

For the future readers (if any), I highly suggest the [Synchronization book](http://books.google.no/books/about/Synchronization.html?id=FuIv845q3QUC&redir_esc=y). In page 31 of the book there is a thorough discussion of the phase. I am not quite sure writing the books material would be a copyright infringement but I highly recommend it to the ones who are curious to learn more.